# Can CloseableHttpClient in httpclient-4.5.2 be shared between multiple requests?

Tags: apache, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

apache httpclient-4.5.2 has a `CloseableHttpClient` class, and it can execute `HttpGet`, `HttpPost` requests. Can different requests share the same `CloseableHttpClient` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can be and it should be. One should have only once instance of HttpClient per aplication or a distinct HTTP service